# Some issues with Bootstrap

Tags: html, web, bootstrap-4

I'm developing a web-audio player, and I'm new to Bootstrap. At the moment, my player looks like this:

[image]

This is my source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>wavesurfer - Intro</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">

    <!-- Waveform -->
    <div id="waveform"></div>

    <!-- Progress -->
    <div class="row">
            <div id="progress" class="col-md-6">Loading audio...</div>
            <div id="duration" class="col-md-6" style="text-align: right;"></div>
    </div>

    <br>


    <div class="row">

        <!-- Backward 5 s -->
        <button id="bwd" class="col-md-3" type="button" disabled="disabled">
            <i class="fa fa-backward"></i>
            <div>Backward 5 s</div>
        </button>

        <!-- Play/Pause -->
        <button id="btn-play-pause" class="btn btn-primary col-md-4" type="button" disabled="disabled">
            <i id="icon-play-pause" class="fa fa-play"></i>
            <div id="text-play-pause">Play</div>
        </button>

        <!-- Forward 5 s -->
        <button id="fwd" class="col-md-3" type="button" disabled="disabled">
            <i class="fa fa-forward"></i>
            <div>Forward 5 s</div>
        </button>

        <!-- Stop -->
        <button id="btn-stop" class="col-md-2" type="button" value="Stop" disabled="disabled">
            <i class="fa fa-stop"></i>
            <div>Stop</div>
        </button>
    </div>


    <br>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <!-- Audio rate -->
            <i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
            <input id="audio-rate" type="range" min="0.25" max="2" value="1" step="0.25">
            <div id="audio-rate_value" style="display: inline;">1x</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" style="text-align: right;">
            <!-- Volume -->
            <i id="icon-volume" class="fas fa-volume-down"></i>
            <input id="volume" type="range" min="0" max="2" value="1" step="0.1">
        </div>


    </div>



    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <!-- Loop -->
            <button id="loop" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Loop</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" style="text-align: right;">
            <!-- Low-pass filter -->
            <button id="lowpass-filter" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Low-pass filter</button>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>

<script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've stumbled upon several issues.

1. **The volume icon** - It changes depending on the volume level, but in a "bad way":

   [image]

   How can I keep it fixed?
2. **Shrinking the screen width** - This is what happens when I shrink my window (I've drawn red rectangles to make the problem clearer):
   [image]
   How can I keep two elements inside the same row?

**EDIT #1** - This is the code for changing the volume icon:

```
var controls = {
...
volume: document.getElementById("volume"),
...
}

controls.volume.addEventListener("input", function () {
let volume = controls.volume.value;
wavesurfer.setVolume(volume);

// Change volume icon
document.getElementById("icon-volume").classList = "";
if(volume == 0){
    document.getElementById("icon-volume").classList = "fas fa-volume-off";
}
else if (volume > 0 && volume <= 1){
    document.getElementById("icon-volume").classList = "fas fa-volume-down";
}
else{
    document.getElementById("icon-volume").classList = "fas fa-volume-up";
}
});
```

Comment: Hi. How do I specify both left and justify in "text-alignment" (if that is the property to be set)?

Comment: No, it doesn't.
By the way, it's the volume div, not the speed one.

Comment: could you show us the code that makes the volume icon change?

Comment: I've fixed the alignment problem. To fix the volume icon problem you need to provide the code that you've tried. So I can see what's wrong

Comment: And what do you mean with a "bad way"?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question so that it contains the js code to change the icon. The 3 icons have different widths. Look at the gif again: with "bad way" I meant that the icon element shifts left/right depending on the icon selected.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually managed to solve Issue #2 by adding the width attribute to the icon tag style:

```
<i id="icon-volume" class="fas fa-volume-down" style="text-align: justify; width: 18px;"></i>
```